Why doesn't KafkaItemReader support auto-rebalance? How to implement it?
I am working with Spring Batch and using KafkaItemReader to read data from Kafka topics. However, I noticed that KafkaItemReader requires explicitly providing the list of topic partitions during initialization. It doesn't seem to handle auto-rebalance when partitions are assigned or revoked dynamically by Kafka.
This limitation requires manually managing partitions, which adds complexity and doesn't utilize Kafka's built-in rebalance capabilities.
My questions are:
Why doesn't KafkaItemReader natively support auto-rebalance in Spring Batch?
Is there any way to handle this limitation, such as implementing a custom ItemReader with auto-rebalance logic?
If anyone has a working example or GitHub link for handling this, could you share it?
Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I believe Spring Batch does not support auto-rebalance because it is designed for batch processing, where it prioritizes determinism and consistency over dynamic rebalancing. When a partition is revoked during a rebalance, ongoing reads could lose continuity, breaking batch processing's expected guarantees.

@JorgeCampos Your comment should be the (accepted) answer.

Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine I'm too lazy now to add more than that :) OP is also asking for other suggestions on how to work around it. I will leave it for someone else to add a more complete answer. Cheers

The answer to the OP is exactly yours + create a custom writer if needed. I will add an answer and cite you.

The following comment by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos is the answer:

Spring Batch does not support auto-rebalance because it is designed for batch processing, where it prioritizes determinism and consistency over dynamic rebalancing. When a partition is revoked during a rebalance, ongoing reads could lose continuity, breaking batch processing's expected guarantees

If you need to support dynamism, you need to create a custom item reader.
